# Получение Имени, Отчества из переменной Name

Tags: powershell, exchange

Есть задача отправки письма новому пользователю домена. Используемая переменная `$Name` содержит "Фамилия Имя Отчество". В письме же нужно оставить только Имя Отчество и убрать фамилию. 
Как это можно сделать?

```
Get-Mailbox | where {$_.WhenCreated -gt (get-date).adddays(-1)} | foreach{
    $name = $_.Name
    $Body = «$name, мы рады приветствовать Вас в нашей компании"
}
```

Получаем:
"Иванов Иван Иванович, мы рады приветствовать Вас в нашей компании"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я еще тот велосипедостроитель.
Попробуйте переменную $name разделить на массив.

```
$namearr = $name.split()
```

А затем, из данного массива, выбрать интересующую вас последовательность ФИО.

```
$nameIO = $namearr[1] + " " + $namearr[2]
```

Соответственно:

```
$Body = «$nameIO, мы рады приветствовать Вас в нашей компании"
```

Comment: Спасибо, большое!! Именно такого результата и добивался!

Answer (score 0):

Regex же:

```
$name = "Фамилия Имя Отчество"
# разбиваем по пробелам, берём вторую и третью части
$NameIO = $name -replace '^(.+)\s(.+)\s(.+)$','$2 $3'
```

Если не любите Regex, то можно так:

```
$name = "Фамилия Имя Отчество"
# разбиваем по пробелам, берём вторую и третью части массива (нумерация с нуля), 
# объединяем элементы массива в строку с разделителем ' ' (пробел)
$NameIO = $name.Split()[1,2] -join ' '
```